# How to use an AVAssetWriter to encode HEVC (Lossless)

Tags: ios, swift, avassetwriter, hevc

I'm aware that the HEVC standard supports [lossless encoding](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/lossless.html), however, it appears that `AVAssetWriterInput` [doesn't have a clear option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocodectype) to write hevc lossless.

How do I set up the `AVAssetWriterInput` to write using the `--lossless` flag in Swift (for iOS)?